# Date attr in ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

how can I tell ember-data to send the value of date attr as timestamp? currently it will be sent over RESTAdapter as string in this format "Mon, 22 Apr 2013 22:00:00 GMT" and my backend (Play-framework with jackson) doesn't want to recognize it

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15695809/what-is-the-best-way-to-modify-the-date-format-when-ember-data-does-serializatio

Comment: thanks. it's the same

Comment: I found that I had to define a custom type as the default serialization of attr('date') wasn't friendly with my django backend (in the dup mentioned above)

Comment: I'm curious, what kind of custom type did you define? I may have the same kind of issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to modify the date format when ember-data does serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15695809/what-is-the-best-way-to-modify-the-date-format-when-ember-data-does-serializatio)