# What is best way to solve html input send data always string, when I use Ember data's DS.attr('boolean')?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I find a problem is `handlebars` `input` set the data. No matter what type of data, the end will be a string. If I use `boolean` or `date`, it will have a problem.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  ...
  sex: DS.attr('boolean'),
  createdAt: DS.attr('date'),
  updatedAt: DS.attr('date')
});
```

I use `select` to change the sex. http://balinterdi.com/2015/08/29/how-to-do-a-select-dropdown-in-ember-20.html

```
<select onchange={{action (mut model.sex) value="model.sex"}}>
  {{#each sexGroup as |sexChoice|}}
    <option value={{sexChoice.value}} selected={{eq model.sex sexChoice.value}}>{{sexChoice.name}}</option>
  {{/each}}
</select>
```

And set the sexGroup in controller:

```
sexGroup: [
  Ember.Object.create({value: 1, name: "man"}),
  Ember.Object.create({value: 0, name: "woman"})
]
```

The problem is whatever my select choice man or woman, Ember data will always send the true to server. Because html select value always is string, and Ember Data `attr('boolean')` get the string will become `true`.

If I must solve this problem, I have two way:

No.1(Not use `boolean`, usr `string`);

No.2(Use `parseInt` to set value before save), look like:

```
this.get('model').set('sex', parseInt(this.get('sexValue')));
```

The `date` format also have problem: [What is the best way to modify the date format when ember-data does serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15695809/what-is-the-best-way-to-modify-the-date-format-when-ember-data-does-serializatio)

So I don't know the role of Ember data `boolean` and `date` attribute types. Especially in the use of html input and the value always is string.

So there is a good solution to this situation? Or am I just using a string? Thanks.

Comment: Ember-data offer [DS.Transform](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Transform.html) class and its `serialize()` and `deserialize()` methods that could help you. 
Implement your own transform object, say `custom-sex` and make your model property be of that type:
    `sex: DS.attr('custom-sex'),`
Everytime request-response will be received/sent, your `serialize()/deserialize()` methods will run.

Comment: @Pavol Thanks. I know this class. But if I use `string` can sovle this problem, why I must custom transform?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `model.sex` use a computed property with `get` and `set`:

```
sexStr: Ember.computed('model.sex',{
  get(){
    return this.get('model.sex') ? 'male':'female';
  },
  set(key,value){
    this.set('model.sex', value === 'male');
    return value;
  }
})
```

Comment: Use `Transform` maybe better than this.